# python: PyQt5 taksbar indicator

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, pyqt5

Trying to find the element which can be used to build an indicator widget for Ubuntu top panel (something similar to http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15708031/Selection_319.png)

Was trying to adapt `QSystemTrayIcon` for this, but it's not what I need... as it's just an icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Gtk3 and implemented the app using it..